# Can I combine a null check inside a LINQ statement?

Tags: c#

Is there an opportunity to combine these two statements and still have wordForm as a variable declared in my method for later use?

```
WordForm wordForm = db.WordForms
    .Where(w => w.Definition == result.definition)
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (wordForm == null)
{
    wordForm = addWordForm(result, word);
}
```

Comment: You can query or insert, but not both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`??`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator) operator:

```
WordForm wordForm = db.WordForms
    .Where(w => w.Definition == result.definition)
    .FirstOrDefault() ?? addWordForm(result, word);
```

Comment: This assumes `addWordForm` returns a `WordForm`.

Comment: Do you mean a case, that `addWodForm` returns a derived class? Just checked - this works.

Comment: What does the ?? operator do?   Yes: addWordForm does return a wordForm: private WordForm addWordForm(WebWordForm result, Word word)

Comment: @Alan It is the [null-coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173224.aspx), you can read about it.

Comment: @kagelos Considering the type of the target variable, it seems like a fair assumption ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the `Where` and the `FirstOrDefault`, as `FirstOrDefault` allows you to specify a predicate. This will save you going through the entire list only to take the first, if it's there. Then you use the null coalescing operator `??`, which will only evaluate the right side if the left side is null:

```
WordForm wordForm = db.WordForms
.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Definition == result.definition) ?? addWordForm(result, word);
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Nevermind, missed the part where OP said he needed the wordForm variable declared!

You could simplify that query to just:

```
if (WordForms.Any(w => w.Definition != result.definition))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not found");
}
```

I would also make sure that "result" is not null first.